# How can I create Hierarchical Container in Vaadin when I am having the duplicate ItemIds? If No, What is the alternate?

Tags: scala, vaadin7

I want to create a tree of user with `n` level Hierarchy. I have a POJO object and within that I have `id,parent_id`.

The problem is user can belong in more than 1 group. So, when I am trying to do,

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      val user_pojo_obj = iterator.next()
      val key = user_pojo_obj.id
      val parent_key = user_pojo_obj.family_id    
      var child: Item = container.addItem(key)
      child.getItemProperty("caption").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(user_pojo_obj.name)
      child.getItemProperty("POJOobj").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(user_pojo_obj)
      container.setParent(key, parent_key)
    }
```

I got NullPointerException at the 2nd line, As per my knowledge it because of the `addItem()` duplication in container, which returns `null`.
Please suggest me the alternate if this can not be improve. (Using Scala)

Thanxx..

Comment: So you have a `User` and a `Group` POJO and a `Group` has `User`s contained? Please clarify your data model. If yes, as far as I know it is not possible that an hierarchical data object has multiple parents. Consider creating a new POJO `ItemXYZ` that wraps users or groups, and that models the hierarchical relation ship via a parent reference to `ItemXYZ`.

Comment: Umm.. No. I have only `user` POJO, Which contains `id` and `family_id` (means parent_id) properties mainly. It also has a property `is_family` which decides whether a object  will act like `user` or `group`. We have one table in database and `user` and `group` stored within that.

Comment: so, we are basically able to code like above. It is working.  Where `key = id` and `parent_key = family_id`. so `setParent(key,parent_key)` works good. The problem comes when we try to do `addItem(key)` with the same key previously added, it returns `null`. We need to that when same `user` belongs in more than one group. `addItem(Obect o)` doesn't allowed duplicates and returns null. In database we use composite key as a primary key so there isn't any inconsistency.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to create a wrapper for your `User` objects because multiple parents are not allowed.

Comment: Basically , duplicate itemIds are not allowed and it throws NullPointerException.   What kind of wrapper, can i make it work dynamically ?

Comment: I guess you want to supply the hierarchical container to a Tree oder TreeTable. So, I would start with the root node(s) and recursively add children. Instead of your `user_pojo_obj.id` you could take a simple counter (Integer) as key, and fill required item properties and set the parent. That way you build the hierarchy in the container in a top-down approach.

Comment: Ya.. I want to supply the hierarchical container to create the Tree.  So, do you mean to say that first i should sort the table (or POJO List ) as per the parent child sequence like, `1.root, 2.parent_1, 3. child_11, 4 child_12, 5. parent_2, 6. child_21, 7. child_22`? and then perform recursion , with adding counter as a `itemId`, right? like `additem(counter)`, and when i need to set parent property, I have to do **`setParent(counter, counter - 1)`** correct ? If anything goes wrong with **`counter -1`** tree won't work. I can't set `family_id` property there because it expects itemId.

Comment: @ParthVishajit, would be nice if you could give a feedback on the answer I posted.

Comment: @Steffen Harbich , sorry for late, I am testing other ideas too. as I have Spark clustering i have another options too. I'll respond you as soon as I will implement the code you suggested. Thank you for Response and answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not have multiple parents or duplicate `itemId`s. The following pseudo-code is an alternate solution which builds the tree-like structure (`node` is your POJO):

```
counter = 0;

function process(nodes, parent) {
    foreach (node in nodes) {
        newId = counter++;
        item = container.addItem(newId);
        // set item caption etc.

        if (parent not null)
            container.setParent(newId, parent)

        process(getNodesWithParent(node), newId);
    }
}

process(getNodesWithParent(null), null);
```

The method `getNodesWithParent` needs to be defined by you. I guess you will take the iterator, iterate through your POJOs and return those with `family_id` equals the parameter's `id`. The overall performance depends on your implementation of `getNodesWithParent`, so if you have a large data set you should care to be efficient.